# Logical equivalence of union, intersection, subsets, and proper subsets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, set-theory

I'm trying to decide which operand of ($\cap, \cup, \subseteq, \subset$) in the $\square$ would make the following expressions true. There can be more than one operand, or none at all:
$$
\text{1)} ~~~~
A \square B ~\equiv ~\forall{x}\big[(x \in A) \Rightarrow (x \in B)\big] ~\land~ \exists{y}\big[(y \in B) ~\land~ (y \notin A)\big] 
$$
$$
\text{2)} ~~~~ 
A \square B ~\equiv ~\forall{x}\big[(x \in A) \Rightarrow (x \in B)\big] ~\land~ \exists{y}\big[(y \in A) ~\land~ (y \notin B)\big] 
$$

For both 1) and 2) I think its $\subset$ because I immediately crossed out $\cap$ and $\cup$ because the first part of each expression $\forall{x}\big[(x \in A) \Rightarrow (x \in B)\big]$ tells me subsets are involved. I eliminated $\subseteq$ because both expressions state that either B has something that A doesn't (like in #1) or A has something that B doesn't (like in #2). Since the subset (A) is missing something from its superset (B), I was thinking the operator $\subseteq$ is invalid. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: You are correct about $(1)$ but not about $(2)$: the expression in $(2)$ is self-contradictory, so it cannot be satisfied.